# How can I simplify $N^{\frac{e}{\sqrt{\log(N)}}}$

Tags: logarithms

I am working through an algorithms workbook and I have the following equation: 
$$N^{\frac{e}{\sqrt{\log(N)}}}$$
I know I can simplify it somehow using the properties of logs and exponents but am a little rusty on that basic math. If you could provide explanation of your process I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fact that $N=e^{\log{N}} $.  Then

$$N^{\frac{e}{\sqrt{\log{N}}}} = e^{e \sqrt{\log{N}}}$$

Not much more I can think of doing here.

Comment: Dang!  That was a pretty bad error on my part this morning.  *Sheesh*  (I can't do arithmatic on a keyboard worth a damn!)

Answer (score 0):

$N^{\frac{e}{\sqrt{\log(N)}}}$

Take the log.   $\log N^{\frac{e}{\sqrt{\log(N)}}} = \frac{e}{\sqrt{\log(N)}}\log(N) =  e \sqrt{log(N)}$.  Raise back to the exponent to get $N^{\frac{e}{\sqrt{\log(N)}}} = e^{  e \sqrt{log(N)}} $ which isn't much better but it has only a single instance of a variable.  If we need to solve for N it will be easy.

Comment: $a/\sqrt a \ne 1/\sqrt a$

Comment: Dang!!!!!  I know better than that!

Comment: It's those dang nested LaTex clauses.  I somehow flipped the terms upside down.  Stupid thing is once I made the error I couldn't see t to proof it.  Very bad error on my part.